# Why would tesseract-ocr fail in this case?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract to recognize characters in this seemingly simple case:

[image]

Yet, the only thing it returns is "5". Why would that be so? Is there anything I can do to fix it? Are there any alternatives (ideally open-source C++) available?

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract is not very good OCR. Also it does not like small images or images with a few characters only. But it is the best open-source OCR, others are worse. Not expensive alternative: http://www.nicomsoft.com/crystalocr/ , expensive (but better): http://www.abbyy.com/ocr_sdk/

Answer (score 0):

The image resolution is too low. Try scan again @ 300 DPI.